# Stop insert rows from clearing first line of data

Tags: excel, vba

I have code that adds 15 rows to a spreadsheet that is copied over to a new spreadsheet. When I insert the rows it looks like it is overriding the first row of data that is already there. I need the first row of data to still be there.

I am using some code I probably found here or on a website. Prior to this I filter all the data and remove the extra categories of rows.

```
'prep for adding departments and department subtotals
Rows("1:15").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

data_sh.Range("G:G").Copy Worksheets("IMPORT-WIP").Range("A1")
Worksheets("IMPORT-WIP").Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates 1, xlYes
```

The first line of the first category is not there.

Comment: `Rows("1:15")` shifts the first row down. Sounds like that should be a `2:16`.

Comment: Also the `Shift` should be `xlShiftDown` instead of `xlDown` (doesn't change the performance, but that is the correct enum member).

Answer (score 0):

I made up an example since you didn't provide one. The animated gif (click to see better quality) first shows 2 sheets and then shows that stepping through the code causes the data from sheet 1 to be copied into the 15 rows inserted at the top of sheet 2 without loss of what was at row 1.

I suggest you verify that this works and then modify the code for your situation.

[image]

```
Option Explicit
Sub insertIntoFirst15rows()
Dim data_sh As Worksheet, data_r As Range
Dim sh As Worksheet, r As Range
Set data_sh = Worksheets("1")
Set data_r = data_sh.Range("A1")
Set data_r = data_sh.Range(data_r, data_r.End(xlDown))
Set sh = Worksheets("2")
sh.Activate
Set r = sh.Rows("1:15")
r.Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown
Set r = Range("A1")
r.Select
data_r.Copy
sh.Paste
End Sub
```